# Laravel put update method doesnt store to databse

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

for some reason, my update method doenst save the changes to the database, when beeing called by a put request. This is my update method:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
        $auftragsPosition = auftragsPosition::findOrFail($id);
        $auftragsPosition->update($request->all());
        return response()->json($auftragsPosition, 200);
    }
```

And this is my route:

```
Route::put("/auftragsPositionen/{id}", "AuftragsPositionController@update");
```

This is my model:

```
class auftragsPosition extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "idAuftragsPosition";
    protected $fillable = array('preis_ges_i_rabatt', 'fk_id_auftrag', 'fk_id_artikel');
}
```

I have checked, that the key and column names match, they do.
I get a 200 response, but the column value doesnt change.
I also checked in the mySQL database, the value is still the same.
Other methods like store (for post) or show(for get) work without a problem.

The request looks like this:

```
PUT /api/auftragsPositionen/52 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Origin: chrome-extension://mmdjghedkfbdhbjhmefbbgjaihmmhkeg
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary6hjR70e6Ig6AXOFC
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InFSVEdqNEZBWk5UVGczMnBHNHhKVXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiV1FuNFwvaG9MTkpIdzJkUTlqUVRcL09PaHIzbEhrY3dBYVFVRTJUek8xUmhqWnZSUDdtclVkUXVyNldIVXo1NXVyamZlbkVpdmtEVUNDTlBEYUdtT202UT09IiwibWFjIjoiYjEyOTQ3NzZlMDdjZDViZDFhN2RjNTc4NTNmMGJiYzA1NThjMjZmY2I2NjM4ODJkZjk1M2NmZTg5ZjAzOWNhNiJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IktKcjlRUVg5eE9nVmltbGdrNm1cL2VBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IitDMzgzOUN5dlVtQjlDTXc2bzNEZzFEcDB1VXNvSnRreW1VQXAxdDl0d290VW9oS2luOWZmeXBKdllwN3QwN2JHam9CZWpIdUd1WjFxVGNjTTZ4MlRRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiIxOTM1MDg2NTVmODgzODZhMTZmNmE2YmVkYzA3MzBhMzFjY2VlNjVhZGQ2YTc5MGYxMTdiNDdmM2YxYjZkYWQ3In0%3D

------WebKitFormBoundary6hjR70e6Ig6AXOFC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fk_id_auftrag"

20
------WebKitFormBoundary6hjR70e6Ig6AXOFC--
```

Comment: Can you show us the `dd($request->all())` response?

Comment: It returns empty Array :/

Comment: I am using Servistate to make the request, btw.

Comment: Then show us your html form code posting this data. Seems like you might be missing the `name` param in html.

Comment: Like I said, I am testing with Servistate, its a Restful API client, where I can generate requests. I am sending form-data with the Key: "fk_id_auftrag" and Value ="20". The Key does match a column name. The method is PUT and the URL is: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auftragsPositionen/52"

Comment: Updated the post with my request

Comment: I have managed, to fix it. The problem is related, to the request im sending. I have used another client, to generate the request and it works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make the fields mass assignable, this can be done on your model by adding the variable `$fillable` which works as a whitelist, or `$guarded` which is a blacklist, it looks like this step is already taken care of, but make sure you have every variable you are trying to update registered.

Then you have to make sure the `$request` is getting filled correctly, with the same keys as the model attributes and a valid value for that attribute type.

The other thing you are missing is that your model is only getting updated on your database by the `update()` method. To get the updated model to return it on the response you need to query the changes again, this can be done easily using the `fresh()` method like `return response()->json($auftragsPosition->fresh(), 200);`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have managed, to fix it. The problem is related, to the request im sending. I have used another client, to generate the request and it works like a charm now.